# What are the clearance requirements to roof eaves for overhead service conductors?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, electrical-distribution

My neighborhood is served by overhead electrical.  My current service drop attaches to the side of my house; the service mast does not extend above the roof.  As part of a larger remodel, the service drop point will need to move.  Currently, the service point is quite far away from any roof overhangs. I'd like to keep the service mast below the roofline, but the new location would have the service drop much closer to the eave (roof overhang).  Can someone point me to Code requirements for clearances *above* the service drop? I can only find Code for clearances below the drop.